# iOS: UISwitch fails to hide with .hidden = YES

Tags: ios, hidden, uiswitch

I have a very simple UI.   you can see from the picture. If the user hits EMIT, it should show the toggles and hide the label readouts.

If the user hits LISTEN it should do exactly the reverse.

Here is the code ( also contained in the screenshot )

```
-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged
{
//    LOG ( @"Seg: %d", segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex );

    BOOL isEmitting = ( segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 );
    BOOL isListening = ! isEmitting;

    self.remoteIOAudioUnit->emitting = isEmitting;

    // hide readout if we're transmitting
    labelA.hidden = labelB.hidden = labelC.hidden = lblCurrentRoom.hidden = ( isEmitting ? YES : NO );

    // hide toggles if we're listening
    switchA.hidden = switchB.hidden = switchC.hidden = ( isListening ? YES : NO );
}
```

As you can see from the screenshot, the breakpoint is getting hit. the code is executing when I toggle the segmented control. but bizarrely the UISwitches fail to hide.

If I hit the other segment (EMIT) it works correctly. ie The labels hide just as they should do.

So why won't the switches also hide?

[image]

Comment: Switches are added in code or in IB? If in IB, outlets to switches are set correctly? Could you modify other UISwitch properties for example alpha value?

Answer (score 1):

Change `( isEmitting ? YES : NO );` to `YES`. Then, if the buttons are still visible, you know your IBOutlets aren't hooked up.

If they disappear, then you know that `isEmitting` is not being set as expected.